# JSF 2 : can EL do something like this?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

This works :

```
<h:outputText value="Active Locale : " /> 
#{view.locale}
```

But how can i achieve something like this with EL ?

```
<h:outputText value="Active Locale Decimal Separator : " /> 
#{new DecimalFormat(view.locale).decimalFormatSymbols.groupingSeparator}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder what you exactly mean with `groupingSeparator`?

The standard `java.text.DecimalFormat` has neither a `getGroupingSeparator` nor `groupingSeparator` field or method. So I'm a bit in the dark what you're actually trying to achieve. Would you like to have the _ printed? So if the local is en_uk, that the result is "_"?

Regardless of what you exactly want, you can pretty much do everything by building your own EL functon. In EL it would then look like this:

```
#{my:someFormatting(view.locale)}
```

someFormatting is then implemented as a static Java method, which you then assign your own namespace ("my" in this case). Look up a tutorial to help you with this if you need that.

There are also a few standard EL functions available to Facelets. These are the JSTL functions defined in the following namespace:

```
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
```

Depending on what you exactly need they may be of some help as well.

Comment: Sorry, it should be something like this in Java : new DecimalFormat(myLocale).getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator(); It's to get the number or currency group separator, like the dot char or the comma char depending on the locale. Thank you for the inputs. So it means i really have to either get it from the managed bean or use custom EL functions. Have a nice day !

Comment: Just to stop anyone else going off on the wild goose chase I just did, the correct namespace URI for the JSTL function library is in fact `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions` (note the `jsp/`).